# OCaml how to convert a polymorphic number to a float?

Tags: polymorphism, ocaml

I want to calculate a polymorphic number.
I know about float_of_int but I want to convert unknown types (int or float) to a float. 
So how can I convert a polymorphic number to a float?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a polymorphic number. There's no predefined OCaml type that is "int or float". What specific OCaml type do you want your function to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making some assumptions on your use case:

```
type i_or_f = Int of int | Float of float;;
let conv x = match x with Int i -> float_of_int i | Float f -> f;;
```

`i_or_f` is the polymorphic type that is either an int or a float.

```
 utop # conv (Int 4);;
 - : float = 4.
 utop # conv (Float 4.);;
 - : float = 4.
```

Is it what you are thinking about ?

Comment: Yes! This is what I want. Thank you! But is it impossible to do this without defining type?

Comment: No, you have to define this type.

Comment: Unless you have the user pass in the right conversion function. Something like `let do_something number_to_float number = Printf.printf "The number is %f\n%!" (number_to_float number)`. Passing in the conversion function is more flexible but also more work for the user.